# Uploading files via JSON Post request to a Web Service provided by Teambox

Tags: java, web-services, json, file-upload

Please refer to(looks pretty simple documentation): https://teambox.com/api/upload

The parameters I am suppose to pass as JSON are:

```
{
  "page_id": 456,
  "project_id": 123,
  "name": "Name",
  "asset": "<File Data>"
}
```

to a URL: `/api/1/uploads`

My guess was that I am to pass a form's encoded request in place of File Data above.
But I keep getting error: /api/1/uploads returned a response status of 422 null

So Here is my code:

A form

```
     <FORM  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION=
"up.jsp" METHOD=POST>
                <br><br><br>
          <center><table border="2" >
                    <tr><center><td colspan="2"><p align=
"center"><B>PROGRAM FOR UPLOADING THE FILE</B><center></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b>
</td>
                    <td><INPUT NAME="F1" TYPE="file"></td></tr>
                                        <tr><td colspan="2">
<p align="right"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File" ></p></td></tr>
             <table>
     </center>      
     </FORM>
```

up.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.sun.jersey.api.client.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.*" %>
<%@ page import="OtherClasses.UploadFile" %>
<%  
         StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
         try 
         {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new   DataInputStream(request.getInputStream()));
            String tmp; 
            while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                inputLine.append(tmp);
                //System.out.println(tmp);
            }
            dis.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
        }
        String encodedRequest = inputLine.toString();
        out.print(encodedRequest);

                Client client = Client.create(); 
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username", "password"));
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://my-server-ip:3000");

        UploadFile file = new UploadFile();
        file.setAsset(encodedRequest);
        file.setName("Afile");
        file.setPage_id("2");//404 error if page doesn't exist.
        file.setProject_id("1");

        ClientResponse r = webResource.path("/api/1/uploads").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class,new Gson().toJson(file));
        System.out.println(r);



%>
```

I keep getting response error code as 422. Please suggest something. What could I try?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a file upload library (such as [Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)) to extract the actual file content (as opposed to the entire request body) and then base64 encode the file into the `asset` field.

As an aside, the API documentation is pretty bad: they say `"<File Data>"` and form encoding but provide no meaningful examples. I'm pretty sure that what you've done (which is read in the entire HTTP request and save that as the `asset` field) will not work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I talked at the teambox community. They said that I should simple submit an html form with the parameters as input fields. That worked. No json required in the request.